# How to make HTML5 color picker to return color name instead of color code?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<label for="background-color">Choose a color for background :</label> 
<input id="background-color" type="color" />
```

I want this to return the color name instead of color code
e.g. "Blue" instead of "#0000ff".

Comment: what will happen if the color selected don't have a friendly name?

Comment: If you want to allow only a set of specific colors, use a drop down...

Comment: What you have tried so far? Where is source code which return color code?

Comment: The OP want to use the HTML5 color picker but want it to return color names instead of codes.

Comment: You need to read [Name that color article and use ntc.js library](http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/). Otherwise, you will need to define your own color set with each hex color code.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#showPaletteOnly").spectrum({
    showPaletteOnly: true,
    showPalette:true,
    hideAfterPaletteSelect:true,
    color: 'blanchedalmond',
change: function(color) {
        printColor(color);
    },
    palette:["red", "green", "blue"],
});
});

function printColor(color) {
alert(color.toName());
   //var text = "You chose... " + color.toHexString();    
   //$(".label").text(text);
    
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.css">

<h2>Palette Only</h2>
<input type='text' id="showPaletteOnly"/>

<br />
<span class='label'>Choose a color</span>
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me

Answer (score 2):

You can use a java script library ["Name that color"](http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var n_match  = ntc.name("#6195ED");
  n_rgb        = n_match[0]; // RGB value of closest match
  n_name       = n_match[1]; // Text string: Color name
  n_exactmatch = n_match[2]; // True if exact color match

  alert(n_match);

</script>
```